# fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:options: My Photo Stream not working

Tags: ios, ios8, phasset, photosframework

I've encountered weird thing with Photos Framework: 
If I fetch PHAssets from PHAssetCollection of a subtype `PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumMyPhotoStream`, I can enumerate them and get for every PHAsset its thumbnail and everything.

But if I try to get those My Photo Stream assets by their `localIdentifier` (meanwhile stored in db) via `fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:options:` I get no results. Assets from other albums are ok, even those from iCloud (`PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumCloudShared`).

Anyone has any ideas why it is so?

Comment: It doesn't happen to me, you might want to show some of your code.

Comment: This happens to me too running iOS 8.4

Comment: can i get cloudOwner name who shared this album?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug and should be fixed in the last iOS 8.2 Beta